# How to load or refresh jTable's data everytime I add new data to ArrayList Object

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Load/refresh jTable everytime I inserted new set of data to arrayList

Already tried those lines I've put on comments but still nothing changed. Consider that adding of those data to arrayList are performed in separate class.So here, Action performed in a jButton so everytime I add set of data from jTextfields and stores it as Object to arrayList, only the first set of columns and rows I inserted to the arrayList are the only displayed data in jTable. Although the second set of data I inserted after clicking the jButton twice was saved to arrayList, the jTable didn't even refresh or load the new data I inserted. Any help will be appreciated

```
//BUTTON ACTION PERFORMED
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) MyJTable.getModel(); 
 tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
//tableModel.setRowCount(0); 
//tableModel.repaint(); 
//int rowCount = tableModel.getRowCount();
//for(int i = rowCount -1; i >= 0; i--){
//tableModel.removeRow(i);
//}
Object[][] displayOnTable = new Object[Data.data.size()][4];
for(int x=0; x < Data.data.size(); x++){
 displayOnTable[x] = Data.data.get(x);  
    }
 MyJTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
 disp,
 new String [] {
 "ID", "Name", "Gender", "Age"
 } ));          
 // --- Declared in Separated class----
 //public class Data {
 //    public static List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
 // }
 // ------------------------
```

Comment: Please  clarify your question and your code as it's kind of jumbled and hard to read.

Comment: Also best to create and post a valid [mcve] program with your question, so that we can test your code ourselves. The [help] and the [ask] can help you with this.

Comment: Side note: no need for you to ever have to call `.fireTableDataChanged()` on a DefaultTableModel object since the object makes the calls *internally* whenever its data is changed, and that is how it is supposed to work. The model itself is responsible for notifying listeners of change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Already tried those lines I've put on comments but still nothing changed.

Well start with something really simple.

Add two lines to your ActionListener:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) MyJTable.getModel(); 
tableModel.setRowCount(0);
```

If nothing happens to the data in the table, then it means you don't have a reference to the table that is visible on the frame. So you need to solve this problem.

Did the data in the table clear? If so this is a good sign as it means your code is referencing the TableModel of the JTable that has been added to the frame.

So now you can add data from the ArrayList.

The basic logic would be:

```
System.out.println( data.size() ); // to verify you actually have data in the List

for (Object[] row: data)
    model.addRow( row );
```

That's it. No need to create a new TableModel. No need to create a 2D array. You will simply iterate through the ArrayList adding one row of data at a time to the model. Then the table will automatically repaint() itself.

Of course this will only work if you have data in the ArrayList.